# Why are the capacitors on the image being used with the DC motor?

Tags: arduino, capacitor, dc-motor, l298

Why are the capacitors on the image being used with the DC motor?

For my arduino aplication with L298n is ok to keep or remove them?

[image]

Comment: related (perhaps duplicate): [Why is this capacitor hooked up to a 9volt electric motor?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/87221/7036)

Comment: They help to suppress the high frequency signals that such motors produce. Without these capacitors it would emit a lot more unwanted radio waves when operated. Operate the motor in the dark and you will see sparks inside, these sparks generate radio waves, that's how they did that in the old days. Do NOT remove the caps, they are there for a good reason.

Comment: Thank you. But the question is if for an arduino aplication with an L298n do I have to remove them or I can keep them?

Comment: @godolomn  Fundamentally, Arduino has nothing to do with this.

Comment: How can you expect anyone to know what they are for besides the person who decided to put them there? Most likely they are there and are needed because something didn't work right without them. If you have a soldering iron, try removing them, but if your stuff doesn't work right, you will have to put them back in. My bet would be that you will need them, so personally, I would not remove them.

Comment: The really big important question is NOT why they are there but why there is a single capacitor in parallel with two series capacitors. This is very likely a bodge so please explain where this picture comes from. Also if you are planning on using the L298 read this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/what-h-bridge-drivers-are-preferred-for-applications-controlling-a-low-voltage-m

Comment: @Andy : it's a terrible photo but I suspect the common node of the "series capacitors" joins to the motor case, making a capacitive delta rather than a bodge.

Answer (score 1):

The caps in your photo are common on commutator type DC machines.Thier purpose isto help EMC because the brushes make lots of electrical noise when the motor is turning .It is quite normal for equipment with such motors like many power tools to fail radiated EMC without them .If you remove the caps its more likely that cummutator hash will find its way into your Aduino causing hassles during debug.OK if you leave them in you do have to be careful about thier charging currents when running say a mosfet PWM buck convertor .The prospective charging currents would make the mosfet run hotter at normal PWM frequencies .The caps wouldnt like the currents anyway.What I do on a buck convertor that drives a motor that may have caps across it is place an inductor in series with the output .For your job 100 microhenry would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Lowers electrical interference. DC motors are usually brushed type and they generate lots of interference when brushes alternate polarity on rotor.